# Enum DropDownList always returns the first value in the list

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, html.dropdownlistfor, editorformodel

I've created several EditorTemplates for some Enums I'm using so that they will display as DropDownLists when I use EditorForModel().  However when I submit the form after selecting an item from the list, It always submits the first item in the dropdown instead of the selected one.

For example, if I have an enum called *"Sizes"* and it has the values *'Small'*, *'Medium'*, and *'Large'*.  EditorForModel will create a dropdown that displays them in the order *'Small'*, *'Medium'*, *'Large'*.  If I then select *'Large'* and then look at the details for the model entry that was made into the database, it will say *'Small'* which is incorrect.

Here's some example code of what I have:

**Sizes.cshtml** (Editor Template)

```
@model Options.Sizes 

@{ 
    var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Options.Sizes)).Cast<Options.Sizes>();

    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items =
        from value in values
        select new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = value.ToString(),
            Value = value.ToString(),
            Selected = (value.Equals(Options.Sizes.Small))
        };
}

@Html.DropDownList("Size", items)
```

**Options.cs** (Class that holds the enum)

```
public class Options
{
    public enum Sizes
    {
        Small,
        Medium,
        Large
    };
}
```

**Create.cshtml** (View)

```
@model = ProjectName.Models.Ball

<form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Ball">
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**Ball.cs** (Model)

```
public class Ball
{
    [Key]
    public Nullable<int> ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Options.Sizes Size { get; set; }
}
```

Somehow the Size property of Ball is always the first value in the dropdown, which is *'Small'*.  No matter what I pick.

Comment: what happens if you don't set the selected value and submit?

Comment: It still uses the first value in the drop down which is actually in the same order as they are declared in the enum

Comment: can you replace the @Html.EditorForModel() with @Html.DropDownListFor and try.

Comment: @JoeHigley, I guess it has something to do with your projection / differed execution . Try to convert your size collection from IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items to List<SelectListItem> items. You may use ToList() extension . Let me know what value you receive after making this change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the dropdown in the browser, with your version you'll see it has the name `Size.Size`. This causes the binding not to work when you post to your `Create` action (assuming that's just expecting a `Ball` model, as you haven't included it here), because that is expecting something with the name `Size`.

It works for me when I change your EditorTemplate so the final line is:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, items)
```

Using `DropDownListFor` ensures the generated `select` element gets the right name.

Comment: This was it.  It also works if I replace `Html.DropDownList("Size", items)` with `Html.DropDownList("", items)`.  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try removing .toString() from value.toString()